# Calculate Absent of Student in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

i am updating an School Application in which i want to calculate absents of any student by their ID and selected time period. i have table in Sql Server named as CHECKINOUT that saves data of students. now i want to calculate absent of any student.when someone enters in school, an entry is made in this table with following fields

```
 [USERID]
  ,[CHECKTIME]
  ,[CHECKTYPE]
```

[image]
this is screenshot of data in CHECKINOUT table

now say i have id 10 and i want to calculate absent of student during last month, i am confused in query. please help me in this

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: i have updated my question @Prdp , i want number of times that student is absent like count(expression)

Comment: unless they are expected to be in school every day you're going to need a table that indicates days they are expected in school.  This could be a table of school in session dates or the students class schedule, something to indicate when an absent should be recorded.  Otherwise any query someone comes up with here will mark weekends and holidays as absents as well as any days they were supposed to be in class.

Comment: if you don't tell us exactly what result you are looking for, we cannot help you, also please exaplin the meaning od the column checktype

Comment: @billpennock holidays are not the issue, here i just want number of times that student is not available in selected dates

Comment: so it's ok if the answer during the last month date range you mentioned says that they were absent every saturday and sunday even if school is not in session?

Comment: CHECKTYPE is the column that is used for verification type like this database is of Time Attandance software so when student enters in, it save checktype as "I" and when goes out it records it as 'O" like in and out

Comment: yeah holidays are not issues, just want to calculate how many times specific ID is not available in the table

Comment: @billpennock will you please post answer?

Comment: done.  please mark as answered if it works for you.  I matched your table in my test.  I ignored the type column as if they checked in or out for a day they must have been in for that day.

Answer (score 0):

was working on it, not sure if this is the easiest but it works, i've tested it.

```
select missDates.userid, checkinout.userid, dt from
checkinout right join  
(select * from (
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) dt
      FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
                  FROM      sys.columns c
              ) nbrs
     WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)) alldates 
     cross join (select distinct userid from checkinout) t2) missDates
         on missdates.userid = checkinout.userid 
         and convert(date,checktime) = convert(date,dt)
 where  checkinout.userid is null
```

Comment: thanks to @Stuart-ainsworth for the sequence of days code

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. why is this error?

Comment: and where to specify the used id which absent is looking for?

Comment: In my test checktime is a datetime field.  is your's for some reason a character field?   if so you'll need to convert it in the data or the procedure

Comment: As for where to get a specific user try adding "and missdates.userid = "the user you want

Comment: I just changed the column in my test to char(25) and that works so perhaps it's your declaration of \@startdate\@enddate.  Mine is:  DECLARE \@StartDate DATE = '20161116'
  ,\ @EndDate DATE = '20161120'